# Cloning a cloned select (issue with resetting value)

Tags: jquery

I have a small piece of code which clones a set of form elements on DOM ready. These can then be inserted by clicking a button, which clones the cloned elements and appends them. I've noticed that for `<select>` elements, the value of the original element is preserved despite being reset when cloned.

Here's a simplified example:

```js
$( function() {

  var $cl1 = $( '.example' ).filter( ':first' ).clone().val( '' ),
      $cl2 = $cl1.clone();
      
  $( 'body' ).append( $cl1, $cl2 );

} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="example">
  <option value="">Please Select</option>
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2" selected>Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

As you can see, the second clone (third select) has the value of the original element, despite being a clone of the first clone, which has no value.

Is this a bug or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: That's ... unsettling, I'll try to fool around the `.clone()` function to see if there is any black magic over here Oo

Comment: @Zenoo Nope, using either of the arguments to `clone()` appear to make no difference. Interesting issue. May be worth poking around in the source of `clone()`: https://j11y.io/jquery/#v=1.11.2&fn=jQuery.clone

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yeah, it seems weird to me, since the second clone shouldn't even be aware of the original data. It should only copy the first clone data.

Comment: `.html()` for both clones has `selected` attribute on the same option as the source element even after `.append`

Comment: I'll look into the `.val()` function, to see what it actually changes.

Comment: Seems to me like `.val()` simply calls `.value` on the select, so this behavior comes from pure JS, not JQuery ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to have to do with `val()` as a setter  doesn't actually remove the `selected` attribute on the `<option>`. Since you aren't setting value property on the second one the browser uses `selected` to set default value

Try

```js
$( function() {

  var $cl1 = $( '.example:first' ).clone();
      $cl1.find(':selected').removeAttr('selected');
      $cl2 = $cl1.clone();
      
  $( 'body' ).append( $cl1, $cl2 );

} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="example">
  <option value="">Please Select</option>
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2" selected>Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It is a solution alright. But can you help us understand what happens in the background which leads to this issue? I find that the object's html and the object are working differently.

Comment: Inspect the live html and look at the option tags. Will still see that `selected` and since you don't set the value property that's what browser knows as the default  You could also set `val('')` on the second clone but removing the `selected` also seems to make sense

Comment: If it's still buggy just set val to empty on both and can also do `prop('selected', false)`

Comment: Ah this makes sense. I think the core issue is that cloning a select doesn't copy over the `value` property, so explicitly setting it in the first clone is the reason why the value is correct despite there being a `selected` attribute present on one of the options, and not on the second, thanks!

Comment: Yes exactly. Am a bit surprised at this one though. Might also be different in more recent versions of jQuery but I suspect not

Answer (score 0):

This behavior seems to come from Javascript's `value` attribute directly :

```js
var a = $('.test').clone();
console.log($('option[selected]',a).text()); //2
console.log($('option:selected',a).text());  //2
console.log(a[0].value);                     //2

a[0].value = '';
console.log($('option[selected]',a).text()); //2
console.log($('option:selected',a).text());  //Empty
console.log(a[0].value);                     //''

var b = a.clone();
console.log($('option[selected]',b).text()); //2
console.log($('option:selected',b).text());  //2
console.log(b[0].value);                     //2

$('body').append(a,b);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="test" class="test">
  <option value="">Empty</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2" selected>2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

As you can see, changing the `value` property from your node doesn't affect the `selected` HTML attribute.  JQuery `:selected` selects the right one.